# Is there a standard format for saving trained logistic regression models?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I was asked in an interview the other day what data structure I would use to save a trained logistic regression model, and I was kind of at a loss for words. I asked for some clarification, but didn't receive much other than just having the question restated. I just said something about how I would use `sklearn.linear_model.Logistic_Regression` to instantiate a model object, and then use the `.fit()` method to fit it, at which point you could save the model with `pickle`/`joblib`. This seemed like it was probably not the right answer, but it was the best I could think of in the moment.

I'm familiar with saving PyTorch models as a `state_dict` which are basically just Python `dict`s, but as far as I'm aware, using `pickle` or `joblib` just save them in a binary format, and I'm not really sure if that even counts as a data structure. (Just a note - the question was not specific to `sklearn` or even to Python, but those are the tools I use most so I defaulted to them.)

After some Googling and digging on SO, I have not been able to find anything that answers my question.

My questions are a) what data structure could you use to hold a trained logistic regression model? And b) is there some widely accepted way of doing this that I'm unaware of? Is there just some gap in my knowledge here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an industry standard called the [Predictive Model Markup Language](https://dmg.org/pmml/v4-4-1/GeneralStructure.html) (PMML).

This standard gives you two data structures for representing linear models:

1. [`RegressionModel`](https://dmg.org/pmml/v4-4-1/Regression.html) - for simpler models
2. [`GeneralRegressionModel`](https://dmg.org/pmml/v4-4-1/GeneralRegression.html) - for unlimited complexity models

Scikit-Learn models fall into the "simpler models" category. You can convert Scikit-Learn pipelines (that end with a final linear model step) using the [`sklearn2pmml`](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package.

The standardized representation of linear models is way more complicated than just capturing the "regression table" part. You will also need to give a complete and unambiguous description of model schema (what are model's input and outputs), specify its applicability domain, etc.

Over the years, various people/projects have dismissed PMML as outdated (mostly due to its XML background), and proceeded to re-inventing their own approach. Hasn't worked out all that well.

Comment: Thanks for the context. I hadn't heard of PMML before. As far as I understand them though, a data structure would be something more along the lines of a dict/map, tree, list, etc. Would a PMML model fall into this category too? From what I understand in your answer, PMML just seems like another file format, similar to a `.pkl` file or something like that.

Comment: PMML provides data structures for "abstracting" fitted ML objects. PMML data structures themselves can be written out in any text data format - the default is XML, but you can also switch to JSON, YAML etc. When you translate a SkLearn `LogisticRegression` model into PMML, then first its `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes are translated to PMML's ``RegressionModel/RegressionTable` data structure. Then, depending on the quality of the PMML converter and the available evidence, additional supporting data structures are added such as `RegressionModel/MiningSchema`, `RegressionModel/Output` etc.

Comment: The original question read "what is the appropriate data structure for storing logistic regression models (long-term)". If the `LogisticRegression` object is dumped in `.pkl` data format you have plain binary serialization. However, if it gets persisted in PMML data format, then two operations take place - first translation from SkLearn data structures to PMML data structures (unified representation of regression tables), and then the serialization of the latter in some text data format. The longevity is achieved exactly by using a non-binary data format.